# Git hub - react portfolio not deployed

Tags: reactjs, github, web, deployment, github-pages-deploy-action

When I tried to publish my react project in git hub page all I could see is only URL and project is not deployed.  Can somebody please help

I tried deploying npm run deploy by changing keys in package json "homepage" , "predeploy" , "deploy".

Comment: are you using react-gh-pages? if not, are you using any library/tools to help you achieve what you need? Also, would you care to provide link to your repo or post the code in you `package.json`?